# Зачем нужны вложенные интерфейсы?

Tags: java

Прогуливаясь по чужим кодам наткнулся на Класс, который содержит внутри интерфейсы:

```
class Aborigen{

interface Arm{
}

interface Hand{
}

//..etc code
}
```

Где это может быть надобно в практическом применении?
Также столкнулся, когда внутри инерфейса классы.
Это чтото новое для меня. Я запутался.

Comment: Например, когда нужно привязать интерфейс к конкретному классу, а не к пакету.

Comment: Для того, чтобы было понятно, с каким классом работает интерфейс и разделить интерфейсы с одинаковыми именами, но используемые разными классами, как тот же интерфейс  `OnClickListener` может реализовать класс `View` и класс `DialogInterface` - имена у интерфейсов одинаковые, но функции разные.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Например, когда нужно привязать интерфейс к конкретному классу.

Классический пример (из мира андроид) [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Суть в том, что `OnClickListener` - это такое абстрактное имя, которое можно прицепить много к чему, а в данном случае дается четкое понимание, что этот интерфейс `OnClickListener` относится именно к `View`

Либо же этот интерфейс нужен исключительно внутри этого класса (ну мало-ли) и его не выносят наружу, что бы не плодить лишних сущностей и не запутывать читателей.

По большому счету - это просто еще один уровень изоляции и организации кода. Есть еще один классический пример (правда с классами, но суть та же) - это классы строители.

Можно сделать два файла/класса: `MyObject` и `MyObjectBuilder`, но более... элегантно, что-ли, будет назвать `MyObjectBuilder` просто `Builder`, поместить его внутрь `MyObject` и вызывать как `MyObject.Builder`